# run application in the background on iOS

Tags: ios, delphi, notifications, firemonkey, delphi-xe7

Personal,

I'm making a mobile application in which I am using Delphi XE7. There's a part of my system that is sending notifications. When I run the application in iOS, this notification not working in the background. When triggered another application on iOS notification of my application stops working, when I open my application notifications again return to work.

Could someone help me on this issue?
As I put the TNotificationCenter running in the background?

I tried using this code

`UIApp := TUIApplication.Wrap(TUIApplication.OCClass.sharedApplication);
 UIApp.setIdleTimerDisabled(True);
 CC := NativeInt(200);
 UIApp.setApplicationIconBadgeNumber(CC);`

Answer (score 0):

Please try this [example for process application in android](http://www.fmxexpress.com/create-an-android-service-with-delphi-xe5-firemonkey/)

Comment: His example is very good, but it works with Android. I need one that works with IOS.